# Large var_dump when looking at $variables

Tags: theming

This might not be the correct place to ask this question, please remove if it is wrong...

But, when I do a var_dump($variables) in one of my nodes I get a very large output that repeats several times... Is this just the way Drupal normally acts or might this indicate that there is something wrong with my site?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of using var_dump(), try enabling the Devel module and doing a `dpm($variables);` - I think you'll like it :)

Comment: Thanks, dpm does work, but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't including lots of unnecessary variables (looks like I don't...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is normal as Drupal pass enormous amount of data trough functions and hooks using array. But for better answer you should provide more information.